# How to add a user defined package/recipe in yocto?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I want to add a program writtem by me to the `Yocto` and make it part of the build through `core-image-minimal`. How do I do this? I really couldn't get much info from the reference manuals regarding this.

Can anyone point me to the link where I can get a step-by-step procedure to add a user defined program?

Comment: It is too broad to answer you here. BTW [Yocto Wiki](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Building_your_own_recipes_from_first_principles) has all infos

Comment: There is a styleguide for writing recipes. Maybe a good starting point as well  [oe-styleguide](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Styleguide#Style_Guidelines)

Comment: This will help you get started : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HsaoVqX7dg

Answer (score 0):

Try

`IMAGE_INSTALL_append += "<your-recipe>"`

In conf file for the machine you are using.